# LaTeX and pandoc templates

Tags: pandoc

I'm wondering where can I edit the default template of LaTeX in pandoc (ubuntu)

I know this is not relevant on TeX forum, but any help would be welcome, because I'm kinda lost.

Thanks!

Comment: A linux user "kinda lost" with the program "foo"?   `man foo` or `info foo` or  `foo  --help `  or  `foo -h`. For quick specific help about "bah" in "foo",  try `foo --help | grep bah`. The Linux terminal  is your powerful  friend, not  a kind of DOS window.

Comment: Indeed, i was looking for a way to know where the data dir was located in linux, but seems i was able to find it with pandoc -v, thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Still off-topic *but* you can print the default template with `pandoc -D latex`, edit it and put it in your personal data directory (`$HOME/.pandoc` on linux):

```
pandoc -D latex > ~/.pandoc/default.latex && $EDITOR ~/.pandoc/default.latex
```

All of this is documented here: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

Comment: It's good that you link to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was looking where the data dir was on linux, and now i found it by typing: pandoc -v, Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

If you do `pandoc -D latex` the template is printed. This works for any format. You could save that template as e.g. 'template.latex' and edit it. You can then point Pandoc to the edited template by doing e.g. `pandoc --template=template.latex`. Or you could call it 'default.latex' and place it in Pandoc's data directory. This will make it the default template.

Comment: I was too late ;)