# Pandoc conversion - LaTeX logo not displaying correctly

Tags: conversion, pandoc

I used `\LaTeX` to get the LaTeX logo in my `.tex` file. However, converting it to pdf with:

```
pandoc file.tex -o file.pdf
```

produces a file that doesn't have the correctly formatted LaTeX logo. However, `pdflatex` works just fine.

How do I resolve this?

**EDIT**: Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\LaTeX{} is a program for typesetting documents.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Pandoc uses by default the `pdflatex` engine for conversion. If I take the one-liner from above:

`\LaTeX is a program for typesetting`

and save it as logo.md and process it

`pandoc logo.md -o logo.pdf`

the result is as expected (a correctly displayed logo).
If you "just" have a complete `.tex` file, I would rather use the `pdflatex` command directly.

Comment: @blue_tiger300 Yes, you're right. I have a complete `.tex` file, and the `pdflatex` command directly works. (I'm left wondering why, though).

Comment: Pandoc sets the option `-s` automatically and uses its internal template to generate the pdf. My guess is that there is clash between your full .tex document and the template. But then again it is just a guess. Maybe you want to open a ticket on the pandoc github site?!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `pandoc file.tex -o file.pdf`? Why are you running pandoc on a latex file?

Comment: I normally use Pandoc to convert pretty much anything. I am learning LaTeX and was trying to integrate it with the tools I use.

Comment: @eshansingh1: That's not a minimal example for Pandoc, is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Don't use pandoc to run LaTeX files. Pandoc is a document **converter** not a LaTeX compiler.
2. Pandoc just behaves as it's supposed to. Pandoc has two parts, a reader and a writer. The reader transforms the input to an abstract syntax tree (AST) that represents the document structure and the writer transforms the AST back into the desired output format.

   So, what happend to `\LaTeX` in your document? The reader translated it to `LaTeX` and stored it in the AST. The latex writer consequently saw only the string `LaTeX` (and not `\LaTeX`) and therefore wrote only `LaTeX`.

   In other words, pandoc **converted** your LaTeX document into another LaTeX document containing only those elements, which can be represented in pandoc's AST.
3. Pandoc's *markdown* reader on the other hand can pass LaTeX code through to the writer. So a markdown file containing:

   ```
   \LaTeX\ is a program for typesetting documents.
   ```

   can be converted to PDF (via latex) with:

   ```
   pandoc file.md -o file.pdf
   ```

   and the logo will be preserved:

   [image]

Comment: The problem with markdown is that you can't use a custom preamble and/or packages (to my knowledge). Guess I'll use `pdflatex` then.

Comment: You can edit the template and/or use header includes, cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296990/latex-and-pandoc-templates/296997#296997