# Set language locale using pandoc

Tags: languages, pandoc

I am writing a book in Spanish, and I would like to have the title of the table of contents in Spanish. I have seen there is a [translation in the pandoc repo](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/3897df868ad1e0ca5409e8fffd86c73dbf6f2b31/data/translations/es.yaml); however, I can't find the way to actually use it. I'm using this for generating the content:

```
pandoc --template=/home/jmerelo/Libros/curso-git/utils/plantilla-kdp.latex \
   -V mainfont=DroidSans \
   -V lang=es-ES\
   -V documentclass=book\
   -S --latex-engine=xelatex  \
   -o aprendegit-kdp.pdf  \
...
```

I have also used `lang=spanish`, `lang=es`, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just carry over latex templates from old versions to new versions. If the template you are using, in this case `plantilla-kdp.latex`, was created for and old version of pandoc, if probably does not have some of the new variables, such as these ones. 
Keep your modifications to the default template in a single place, generate a new template in the way it's explained here: [LaTeX and pandoc templates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296990/latex-and-pandoc-templates) , and copy/paste your modifications to the new template.